Is there a topological space with boundary that is an interval?
If the topological space $X$ we are interested in is a CW-complex or singular complex or such, then $\partial^2 = 0$ necessarily holds. So it is impossible for $\partial X = I \simeq [0,1]$ since that would imply $\partial^2 X \simeq \{0,1\}$.
Now, my question is, can this be made to be possible with some relaxed condition on $X$? Would it require a very odd topology put on $X$, or could it be constructed intuitively (e.g. $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual topology)?

In your example the boundary map is an additional structure. Generally, a topological space only has $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus\text{int}(A)$. You're confusing the two type of boundaries it seems?

$\partial^2 = 0$ is a statement about the differential in the chain complex(es) defining homology. Although its idea is closely related to the topological boundary, it is not the topological boundary for which $\partial^2 = 0$ most definitely doesn't hold: If you consider $I \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, say, then $\partial I = I$.

Oh wow, that cleared it for me. I was not aware that topological boundary is not the same as boundary of a complex or a manifold

I guess one could take $X = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash I$ with $I = [0,1]$ and topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$. The claim then follows from
$\partial X = \overline{X} \cap \overline{X^c} = \mathbb{R}^2 \cap I = I$.
Admittedly, this example seems a bit artificial.

This example also shows that what OP said about $\partial^2 = 0$ is nonsense: $X$ is a surface and therefore admits a CW-structure.
